# Mongoose find by nested objectIds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema set up:

```
var movieSchema = new Schema({
    budget: { type: Number },

    website: { type: String },

    genres: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Genre' }]
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
});
```

I'm then trying to look up the genres property by using $in like this:

```
//find all genre
Movie.find({ genres: { $in: [ mongoose.Types.ObjectId('57fd69f24704d92f06000094') ] } }, function(err,  docs) {
    console.log(docs);
});
```

But the results are not returning. It works in CLI mongo, but I can't do the find with Mongoose.

Comment: should work, what are the results if you are doing this query not via `mongoose`? like with robomongo?

Comment: You don't need to use the `$in` operator. `{ genres: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('57fd69f24704d92f06000094')  }`